# strange results for double values in swift

Tags: swift

why i’m getting this strange result in swift for double values

```
let x = 1000000000000000000000.0;
let y = 1000000000000000000001.0;

print(x-y);    //0      but should be -1
print(y-x);    //0      but should be 1
print(x==y);  //true    but should be false
```

i’m using **swift 3**

Comment: So basically Double range in swift is `1e+15` and you use `1e+21`

Comment: i wondering why the question marked as duplicate??!! it's nothing to deal with floating point

Comment: You can open it with add more specific query..!!